# Linux/Raspberry Pi command to help round to 2 decimal

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am running the following command to get Free Memory, and want to change it from KB to MB to the second decimal.

```
grep MemFree /proc/meminfo | awk {'print $2*.001'}

Output: 96.163 | Want it to be Output 96.16
```

How do I round? I have seen where it says to use scale=2, but then it just prints out scale=2, I have tried puttting it before anfer and inbetween several different ways with no luck. how can I do this.

I am editing the .bashrc file to I can see the output in MB no KB

Comment: As some backstory, by the way -- `scale` is meaningful in `bc` only; it has no particular meaning in `awk`, or in other non-`bc` tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/MemFree/ { printf("%0.2f\n", $2 * .001) }' /proc/meminfo
```